# Write unit test for function calling Async request and return nothing

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

Here is my ViewModel Call with function fetch Products, I need to test function which is internally calling Async request and setting some data

```
class ViewModel : NSObject {
    public var array : [Product]?
    func fetchProduct() {
        ProductRouter.fetchByCategory.send(modelType: ProductSearchResponse.self, success: { (success) in
        self.array = (success as! ProductSearchResponse).skus
    }, fail: { (error : NSError) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }, showHUD: true)
   }
}


class MyNetworkRequestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.

       let url = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "Listing", withExtension: "json")!
       let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
       stub(uri(ProductRouter.fetchByCategory.path), jsonData(data))
       let vm = ViewModel()
       vm.fetchProduct()
       XCTAssertNotNil(vm.sku)              
  }
}
// Json File have some Listing.json have correct json format.
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is set up an expectation and wait for it

```
class MyNetworkRequestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
       let expectation = expectation(description: "fetch expectation")
       let url = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: "Listing", withExtension: "json")!
       let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
       stub(uri(ProductRouter.fetchByCategory.path), jsonData(data))
       let vm = ViewModel()
       vm.fetchDone = {
            expectation.fullfill()
       }
       vm.fetchProduct()
       waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
             XCTAssertNotNil(vm.sku)
        }
  }
}
```

The "fetchDone" is this case will be whatever tells your viewController that the data has arrived. Basically looking like this:

```
class vc: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let viewModel = vm()
        viewModel.fetchDone = {
            self.populate(array: viewModel.array)
        }
    }

    func populate(array: [String]) {

    }
}

class vm: NSObject {
    var fetchDone: (() ->())?
    var array: [String] = [] {
        didSet {
            fetchDone?()
        }
    }

    func fetchProduct() {
        // Do something
        self.array = ["some data"]
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using mokingj (stub) . seem like in my above code :      stub(uri(ProductRouter.fetchByCategory.path), jsonData(data)).  it is not conning to Json File , it directly hitting Server .

Comment: Is the problem that you want it to get json file instead?

Comment: yes  any other Problem,i want to get data from Json file but , it is hitting server directly . i already using stub(uri(ProductRouter.fetchByCategory.path), ProductSearchResponse(map: jsonData(data))) ,Not sure why it calling network again and again. ProductSearchResponse (is my Object Mapper Class)

Comment: Ah, quite misleading title. I have not worked with stub for a long time. But it looks like you should have a flag wether you want to run on server or file. Like ’fetchProduct(offline: true)’ and in the function you run ’if offline { stub.... }’ of course in the long run this should be on a desperat level. Probably right before executing the request and not bound to a bool but what scheme you are running

Comment: is this good practice to use fetchDone() clouser or delegate is good? because I want to write clean and testable with good practice code.

Comment: It’s all up to you. I personally dont feel that protocols should be used as callbacks. Especially if you are going to make rapid page changes as you want to use weak self among other things. So yes, i would say closures are better than protocol delegates in this scenario

Comment: For good practice  : where should we call fetchProduct() in ViewModel class  in init Function or separately call in viewController,  vm. fetchProduct()  in viewdidload.